# PHP export to text file - Only saving first line

Tags: php, mysql, file, text, save

I'm trying to export some extracted $_POST information into a text file, however my code is only capturing the first variable and ignoring the rest. I'm saving the information to the text file in this manner:

```
$values = "First Name: $fName\r\n";

$values .= "Last Name: $lName\r\n";

$values .= "Address: $address\r\n";
```

etc.

This is the code I use to write to the text file:

```
$fp = @fopen("person.data", "w") or die("Couldn't open person.data for writing!");
$numBytes = @fwrite($fp, $values) or die("Couldn't write values to file!");

@fclose($fp);
```

Any ideas on why it would only save the first $values ($fName) variable but not the rest of them? It actually saves the first part of the $values string for all of them (so I see Last Name:, Address:, etc. on separate lines in the text file) but the called variables $lName and $address do not appear.

Comment: please post the part of the code where you assign values to the variables that are not showing..

Comment: I would try: `echo $values;` before you actually write the file and make sure the values `$lname` and `$address` are actually set and being appended to `$values` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
file_put_contents('person.data', $value);
```

See http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Instead of `"\r\n"` you can use the constant `PHP_EOL`, which will contain the correct newline character(s) for the platform you are running the script on.

Answer (score 0):

I see the variables are $lName - is it a case sensitivity thing? What happens if you echo the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue - the problem was I wasn't naming the other pieces within a hidden form I created, like I did for the person's first name.

Answer (score -2):

```
$values = "First Name: $fName\r\n";

$values .= "Last Name: $lName\r\n";

$values .= "Address: $address\r\n";
```